# Show Part of Sliding Content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, slider, slidetoggle

I have an element that I would like to show a part of by default (say 100px), but then show the rest of it by clicking a link. I found this [site](http://sim.plified.com/2008/09/15/sliding-content-from-a-partial-height-with-jquery/) that has a solution to it because it does not seem to be possible with jQuery's built-in slideToggle. This solution works (as shown in the code below), but does not work with multiple sliders on the same page. I know I need to somehow switch out '.slider' with the id for the specific slider, but am not sure how to do that. I need to grab the current ID, but using this with the openSlider and closeSlider functions does not work. Can anyone help? I'm sure it is a rather simple issue I just can't seem to figure out.

**the HTML**

```
<ul class="slider" id="1-slider">
  <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/490x340" alt="#" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/490x340" alt="#" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/490x340" alt="#" /></li>
</ul> <!-- .images -->

<div class="slider_menu"></div>
```

**the jQuery**

```
var sliderHeight = "100px";
$('.slider').each(function() {
    var current = $(this);
    current.attr("box_h", current.height());
});

$('.slider').css("height", sliderHeight);
$(".slider_menu").html('<a href="#" class="expand">Expand</a>');
$(".slider_menu a").click(function() {
    openSlider();
    return false;
});

function openSlider() {
    var open_height = $('.slider').attr("box_h") + "px";
    $('.slider').animate({
        "height": open_height
    }, {
        duration: "slow"
    });
    $(".slider_menu").html('<a href="#" class="expand">Collapse</a>');
    $(".slider_menu a").click(function() {
        closeSlider();
    });
    return false;
}

function closeSlider() {
    $('.slider').animate({
        "height": sliderHeight
    }, {
        duration: "slow"
    });
    $(".slider_menu").html('<a href="#" class="expand">Expand</a>');
    $(".slider_menu a").click(function() {
        openSlider();
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script should like this :

```
var sliderHeight = "100px";
$('.slider').each(function() {
    var current = $(this);
    current.attr("box_h", current.height());
});

$('.slider').css("height", sliderHeight);
$(".slider_menu").html('<a href="#" class="expand">Expand</a>');
$(".slider_menu a").click(function() {
    openSlider($(this).parent().prev("ul.slider"), $(this).parent());
    return false;
});

function openSlider(obj, slideMenu) {
    var open_height = $(obj).attr("box_h") + "px";
    $(obj).animate({
        "height": open_height
    }, {
        duration: "slow"
    });
    $(slideMenu).html('<a href="#" class="expand">Collapse</a>');
    $(slideMenu).children("a").click(function() {
        closeSlider(obj, slideMenu);
    });
    return false;
}

function closeSlider(obj, slideMenu) {
    $(obj).animate({
        "height": sliderHeight
    }, {
        duration: "slow"
    });
    $(slideMenu).html('<a href="#" class="expand">Expand</a>');
    $(slideMenu).children("a").click(function() {
        openSlider(obj, slideMenu);
    });
    return false;
}
```

Hope this will fix your problem !!

Comment: Maybe you can explain to the OP what you changed and what the problem was.

Comment: That works! Thanks so much. So it looks like you passed those items in as parameters of the function. I thought that was the way to do it, but wasn't sure how to actually write it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I was having this problem before, but it seems to keep jumping to the top of the page when I try to close a section. Usually that is because "return false" is not in place, but I have that included in both functions. Any idea what might be causing that to happen?

Comment: @Andrew, i think its because of that hash which you specified for href attribute in expend/collapse hyperlink. Try removing them and check again.

Comment: @Kundan Is there something I should replace it with? When I remove it completely, it seems to refresh the page when I try to collapse the section.

Comment: @Andrew, just replace it with "javascript:void(0);".